# How to Add Author Editing Capability to Existing Post by Admin

Tags: author, user-roles, user-access, account

I apologize if this is mentioned on here but I can't find any information!

Anyway, I am building a WordPress site where I created the content with my administrator account.  However, once the site is launched there are going to be 10-15+ Author accounts in order to manage a single custom post each.

Is there any way that I can create a new account, and add author capability to a post which already exists but is not created by them?

Or is there a way I can change the author on an existing post from the admin account to the newly created one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a capability that's named `edit_others_posts`, that you can assign to users or roles. But there's also an easier way to do this: The (by default) hidden "Author" meta box.

#### How-to change the author of a post

[image]

<sup>1. Click the "screen options" tab on the upper right of the admin screen.
2. Check the "Author" checkbox</sup>

[image]

<sup>3. Choose the author of the post</sup>

Comment: Thanks - this is actually for a custom post type so I had to add a single line to my functions.php file - add_post_type_support('my_post_type', 'author'); - 
After that, your instructions worked like a charm!

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: Okay, I have another question about this.  Is there a way I can setup these 'Author' accounts so that they can edit and publish a single custom post where I set them as the author... however restrict them from authoring and publishing normal generic posts or blog posts?

Comment: @delvec [Just take a look at Roles & Capabilites in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). You can assign/remove every cap to every role and/or user.